# Slow booting and reactions Linux Lubuntu on NTB HP – Compaq 6710b

Tags: system-installation

Very long all reaction times and booting time. System Lubuntu 18.04. LTS.  Ntb has 2 core intel, 3GB Ram
Thank you for help very much.

[image: 1]

Comment: You're having problems with your video driver or video card. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `dkms status`.